# how to copy one field value into another field in a jsp page

Tags: jsp

I have got an issue with the jsp page. I do not know how to pass one field value from one textbox into another textbox. With JavaScript, it's quite easy as I can use Document.getElementID. Please help me out.

To give you an idea what I like to achieve is stated in below:

1. I have got a form which has a checked box along with other fields
2. Based on the checked box's value I will set the boolean flag which will be stored in a hidden field on the same jsp page.

With jquery or javascript it's pretty simple to achieve. but I am not using those things as per the project guideline. So it's a rudimentary jsp page with html tags embedded with it.

Please let me know how to get it working.

Comment: As you said `With JavaScript, it's quite easy as I can use Document.getElementID`

Comment: Please Post the code what you tried

Comment: Why exactly do you need to copy a value from one input to other input? What exactly are you attempting to achieve with this? This sounds too much like you're looking in the wrong direction for the solution and/or are overcomplicating simple things due to lack of basic HTTP/HTML knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value in a variable inside jsp scriptlet.And access that value any where in jsp.

```
<% var x = Math.getRandom(); %>
```

Now in jsp access this value as

```
<%=x %>
```

While user will not see jsp page.Page is always html view generated by jsp.So in that case it can only be accessed via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

write onchange event in 2nd text field and write the function for onchange in that function 
get the element by either name or id and copy it in 2nd text field as

```
document.getElementByid('2ndTxt').value= document.getElementByid('1stTxt').value
```